# Real Analysis Set - Basic topology

Tags: real-analysis

I have got troubles with proving the set $\{1+1/2+\cdots+1/n : n \text{ is natural number}\}$ not closed. I tried to use theorem that a set is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequence contained in that set has a limit point that is also an element of that set. I considered the partial sum that $S=1+1/2+\cdots+1/N,$ is there a way I could show that the set is not closed.

Comment: Be careful: The condition that every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit in the set is the definition of *completeness*, not *closedness*!

Comment: This set is closed in $\mathbb R$ because it has no limit points in $\mathbb R.$ It is not closed in $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

You are in trouble, since the set is closed. More generally: if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, then the set $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ is closed. This is so becouse otherwise there would be a number $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ which would be the limit of a sequence of numbers of the form $x_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$). But every interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ only contains finitely many $x_n$'s.